# Translate from table design to SQL Create query?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]
<sub>(source: [joescott.me](http://share.joescott.me/29bd.png))</sub>

I'm currently grappling with the following, as the title suggests i'm looking to reverse this table design into a valid create query for the table 'Book'

Am i right in thinking:

- The title should be used as a primary key?
- A foreign key reference publisherName on **Publisher(name)**
- And another authorName on **Author(name)**

Which becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    Title varchar(30),
    ISBN INT UNIQUE,
    Cost dec(8,2),
    authorName varchar(30) REFERENCES Author(name),
    publisherName varchar(30) REFERENCES Publisher(name)
);
```

After mentioned alterations:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    Title varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ISBN INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    Cost dec(8,2) NOT NULL,
    authorName varchar(30) REFERENCES Author(name),
    publisherName varchar(30) REFERENCES Publisher(name)
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the ISBN be a better primary key for books?  And where is your primary keys for the author and publisher tables?

Comment: please clarify which DB you're planning to work on? The keywords vary across MySql, SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Oracle! :)

Comment: was an answer just deleted? it was a good one! I made the changes in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make the best out of this bad design, you should go for your 2nd option:

- Table [Publisher] with PK 'Name'.
- Table [Author] with PK 'Name'.
- Table [Book] with PK 'ISBN' and FK [Publisher].Name and another FK [Author].Name.

(PK should be standard UNIQUE and NOT NULL)

`CREATE TABLE Book (
    Title varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ISBN INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    authorName varchar(30) REFERENCES Author(name),
    publisherName varchar(30) REFERENCES Publisher(name) );`

Also with this dataset, your char lengths are fine. But in reality, INT will be too small to store 13 digit numbers for ISBN, and names can go up to 40+ chars easily, especially publishers.

Comment: All the answers are correct and very useful, i just found this answer the most approachable. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> The title should be used as a primary key?

No. A primary key should be unique, and unchanging. There is no way to guarantee that there aren't two books with the same title. I believe ISBN is guaranteed unique and unchanging, although books exist without ISBNs (books that are not yet finished, books published before ISBNs became popular).

> A foreign key reference publisherName on Publisher(name)

Again - you want the primary key for "publisher" to be unique, and unchanging. There's no guarantee that publisher names are unique, or unchanging. Typically, we create "publisherID" as primary keys, with either a GUID or incrementing integer.

> And another authorName on Author(name)

As above

Also, I wouldn't include "numberOfTitles" in the publisher table - normalization suggests that we need to calculate this value, rather than store it.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to use duplicate columns (publisher name, author name) in your books table.

Just make a primary key column `(Publisher_Id), (Author_Id)` in both your Publisher & Authors table. Reference these columns as a foreign key in your books table & then you can get the publisher_name & author_name or any columns from both the tables using a SQL join.

So your books table would become

```
Book_Id(PrimaryKey)   Book_Name   Publisher_Id     Author_Id
     1             C# at a glance     100             21
```

You can use simple queries like

```
  select a.book_name,b.publisher_name,c.author_name from books a
  inner join publisher b on a.publisher_id=b.publisher_id
  inner join authors   c on a.author_id=c.author_id
  where a.book_id=1;
```

Don't set book_name as a primary field column. Instead you can use `ISBN` or make a separate `book_id` column. Also look into database normalization & perform the relevant forms upto 3NF minimum before you design your database depending upon your requirements. [1NF, 2NF, #NF, BCNF Normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: Without altering the other two tables, is the revised query in my edit what we're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

### Data  Structure
Employee  Details (Master Table)
• Employee ID (Primary Key) (Alphanumeric)
• Name (String)
• Age(Integer)
• Joining Date(Date)
• Designation(String)
Salary Details (Child Table)
• Employee  ID (Foreign Key) (Alphanumeric)
• Salary  ID (Primary Key) (Alphanumeric)
• Year(Date)
• Month(Date)
• Gross Salary(Integer)
• Deduction(Integer)
• Net Salary(Integer)
• Currency(String)

Prep pare a Master grid with sub grid- Master grid shows employee details and associated salary details shows in sub grid. Sub grid will have multiple rows like one employee have multiple salary based on year and month.

Top add & Delete icon for  Adding or Deleting Employee Details
Grid level add option for adding salary details in sub grid under each employee
Pen icon  for edit  in raw level - edit employee or salary details
Provide separate popup for adding / updating employee or salary details
Add/Update pop should be with proper validations
Use connection string in webconfig to connect to database
All data fetching will be using on Views
All data insertions, Update and delete will be using stored procedure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).